# Collapsible tableview displays just only grey bars when the app has been released

Tags: ios, swift, app-store

While the application is in developing, everything works well. The table displays all the data properly.

[image: second]

After the application has been released on Appstore, the table goes crazy. There are grey bars as TableViewCell/header instead of the corrected ones.

[image: first]

I try to summarize my code, change the header's height via its delegate and submit it to test flight. Nearly an hour, the "processing" step finished, I try it on the test flight, the problem stills.

I don't know what happens. This has been archived; no one can live-debug it. I have no idea to deal with it.

Comment: set your application in release mode and debug. same issues  you can see.to see this on device or simulator, just slow down animation

Comment: for more information paster your code

Comment: @ajjjjjjjj - Thank you for your advisory. In the release environment, I found that 'viewForHeaderInSection' not being called. Is there something in release envi does effect to tableview delegate?

Comment: relase mode just unhide, covered bugs